# Auto-Sklearn: Is it possible to integrate a metric of imblearn as a scorer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, automl, imblearn

I would like to use the geometric mean as a metric to optimize classification models trained with the fit() method.
I thought that the autosklearn.metrics.make_scorer() would allow to define the geometric mean as a scorer like this:

```
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, feat_type=feat_type, metric=autosklearn.metrics.make_scorer("gm", imblearn.metrics.geometric_mean_score))
```

as the imblearn-package is fully compatible with sklearn.

However, after the model has been "fitted" using the gm as defined above, the sprint statistics indicate that the definition as I did it does not seem to be working:

```
auto-sklearn results: 
Dataset name: 6b31930a65e59cca700a5844fbab91a0 
Metric: gm 
Best validation score: 0.000000 
Number of target algorithm runs: 187 
Number of successful target algorithm runs: 82 
Number of crashed target algorithm runs: 74 
Number of target algorithms that exceeded the time limit: 18 
Number of target algorithms that exceeded the memory limit: 13
```

Does anyone know why Auto-Sklearn seemed to be working with the GM but resulted in a score of 0,0000? Did I do anything wrong? Is it somehow possible to define the geometric mean as a metric to optimize the model other than using the imblearn package? The metric is as far as I know not integrated within sklearn (yet)? Or does anyone know any other way how I could potentially use the geometric mean within Auto-Sklearn?